# How to configure firestore with @angular/fire 17 and ionic @ionic/angular 7.6.2 to work completely offline?

Tags: android, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm relatively new to serious app development with angular ionic and firebase.

I'm now trying to figure out how to configure offline capabilities / unlimited cache size with angular fire, for days - and I'm absolutely lost!

I can not even find a good peace of documentation for this, which makes me wonder, if this is even possible, although quite a lot of existing API code in angular/fire suggests that it should be somehow possible.

What I was able to achieve so far is using the disableNetwork() and enableNetwork() functions, which then really result in data being loaded from the cache. But this does not help me at all - if there is no network connection at the point of time when the app starts - in this situation I'm just completely stuck at the point of time when I'm trying to load the first piece of data from firestore. Also this is not what I need, because it is not persisting any changes which are made to the date while being offline and this is a core feature of firebase (and I'm not sure how much of this is supported in angular/fire).

I really hope you guys can help me with this and I appreciate any hint.

The way I'm initializing firebase so far is visible in the conde snippet below.

My main.ts of the standalone angular app that I'm working on:
Please note: That there is no code that tries to configure anything related to offline storage / unlimited caching, as I'm absolutely clueless and everything I tried so far was not successfull.

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, enableProdMode, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { routes } from './app/app.routes';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';
import { Drivers } from '@ionic/storage';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getAuth, provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { getAnalytics, provideAnalytics, ScreenTrackingService, UserTrackingService } from '@angular/fire/analytics';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore, CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED, getPersistentCacheIndexManager, enablePersistentCacheIndexAutoCreation, PersistentLocalCache, Firestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { FirestoreDataService } from './app/firestoredata.service';
import { AuthService } from './app/services/auth.service';
import {Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}



bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    importProvidersFrom(
      IonicModule.forRoot({}),
      IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
        driverOrder: [Drivers.IndexedDB, Drivers.LocalStorage],

      }),
    ),
    provideRouter(routes),
    importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule),
    importProvidersFrom(TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })),
    importProvidersFrom(provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig))),
    importProvidersFrom(provideAuth(() => getAuth())),
    importProvidersFrom(provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics())), 
    importProvidersFrom(provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())),
    ScreenTrackingService, UserTrackingService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: () => initializeMyApp,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AuthService, FirestoreDataService, Firestore]
     }
  ],
});

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after quite a lot of banging my head against the nearest wall, I finally came up with a not very satisfying solution which you can find below. The FIXME which I left there would still be something for which I would be very grateful to have a solution..

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, enableProdMode, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { routes } from './app/app.routes';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';
import { Drivers } from '@ionic/storage';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FirebaseApp, initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getAuth, provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { getAnalytics, provideAnalytics, ScreenTrackingService, UserTrackingService } from '@angular/fire/analytics';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore, PersistentCacheSettings, CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED, getPersistentCacheIndexManager, enablePersistentCacheIndexAutoCreation, PersistentLocalCache, Firestore, persistentLocalCache, initializeFirestore, FirestoreSettings, PersistentTabManager, persistentMultipleTabManager, enableIndexedDbPersistence } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { FirestoreDataService } from './app/firestoredata.service';
import { AuthService } from './app/services/auth.service';
import {Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

let fsapp: FirebaseApp ;
let fs: Firestore;

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    importProvidersFrom(
      IonicModule.forRoot({}),
      IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
        driverOrder: [Drivers.IndexedDB, Drivers.LocalStorage],

      }),
    ),
    provideRouter(routes),
    importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule),
    importProvidersFrom(TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })),
    importProvidersFrom(provideFirebaseApp(() => 
    {
      fsapp = initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)
      return fsapp
    }
    )),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: () => initializeMyApp,
      multi: true,
      deps: []
    },
    importProvidersFrom(provideAuth(() => getAuth())),
    importProvidersFrom(provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics())), 
    importProvidersFrom(provideFirestore(() => fs)),
    ScreenTrackingService, 
    UserTrackingService
  ],
});

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}


function initializeMyApp(): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {

    console.log("initializeMyApp")
    
    const plc = persistentLocalCache( {cacheSizeBytes: CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED, tabManager: persistentMultipleTabManager()} as PersistentCacheSettings ); //
    initializeFirestore(fsapp, { cache: plc } as FirestoreSettings);
    fs = getFirestore()

    // FIXME in future: Not sure why the above code does not get the job done of this deprecated enableIndexedDbPersistence function...
    enableIndexedDbPersistence(fs, { forceOwnership: !globalThis.localStorage }) // forceOwnership for web worker
    .then(() => console.log("Offline persistence enabled"))
    .catch(error => {
        switch (error.code) {
            case 'failed-precondition':
                console.log("Offline persistence already enabled in another tab")
                break
            case 'unimplemented':
                console.log("Offline persistence not supported by browser")
                break
            default:
                console.error(error)
        }
    })

    const im = getPersistentCacheIndexManager(fs)
    if(im!=null){
      enablePersistentCacheIndexAutoCreation(im);
    }
        
    resolve( )

  });
}
```